# Creating an ID for a Form Variable (or Changing it) Using Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am receiving an XML data form result and using the Strophe library to convert it into html.

This gives me a chunk of HTML (form) as a variable, which I can then append to a page:

```
var iqHtml = iqForm.toHTML();
$("#form-result-div").append(iqHtml);
```

The issue is that the form which it attaches has no id, action, or anything to identify it:

```
<form data-type="result">
...
```

I have two possibilities here.

---

Option 1. (preferred method)

Is it possible to change the variable iqHtml, which is just raw HTML, and an ID to it? Ideally this would be done before it is appended to the page.

I've tried multiple ways to find the form tag and add the attribute using .find() and .attr() but with no success.

---

Option 2. (less preferable)

I can edit the library to add a random ID (say id="some-id") which I will then need to EDIT rather than creating new.

This editing will have the questions as Option 1 - how do I search the variable and then change the form's ID.

---

Thank you.

Kind Regards,

Gary Shergill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign an id before appending it

```
$(iqHtml).attr('id', 'someid').appendTo("#form-result-div");
```

Edited: id needs to be in ''

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! I edited the answer slightly, the id needed to be wrapped in '' otherwise it wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var iqHtml = "<form><input type='text' /></form>";

$("#form-result-div").append(iqHtml).find("form").attr("id", "myForm");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AA8Cf/

You can also play with one of the `child` selectors to pick up a specific one, if there is more than one form.

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/child-filter-selectors/

Comment: Luckily only one form is returned so there's no need to find a specific form. This solutions works as well thank you, but I went with towr's response as it adds the id before it is appended. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Both ways should give you the result expected.